# How to push a key value pair in multi dimensional array php

Tags: php, php-5.3

Using following foreach loop

```
$category_ids = array_of_ids;

foreach($category_ids as $category_id) {
    $queryAllProducts['products'][] = $this->api->queryAllProducts(array('params' => array('categoryCode' => $category_id, 'usertoken' => USER_TOKEN))));
    }
```

As a result of the above loop I get the following struction. 
Now how can I add a `category_id` after `productName`.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [result] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [products] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Product] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [price] => 0.72
                                            [productName] => product_name_appears_here
                                        )

                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [price] => 0.72
                                            [productName] => product_name_appears_here
                                        )

                                    [2] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [price] => 0.72
                                            [productName] => product_name_appears_here
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [result] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [products] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Product] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [price] => 3.19
                                            [productName] => product_name_appears_here
                                        )

                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [price] => 1.12
                                            [productName] => product_name_appears_here
                                        )

                                    [2] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [price] => 1.66
                                            [productName] => product_name_appears_here
                                        )

                                    [3] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [price] => 1.66
                                            [productName] => product_name_appears_here
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
```

How can I handle this kind of situation.

**My expected output**

For sample Ill show just 2 array

```
[0] => stdClass Object
          (
                  [price] => 0.72
                  [productName] => product_name_appears_here
                  [category_id] => something_which_is_from_$category_id
          )

[1] => stdClass Object
          (
                  [price] => 0.72
                  [productName] => product_name_appears_here
                  [category_id] => something_which_is_from_$category_id
          )
```

Comment: You give an example of the structure you get, can you also provide a corresponding example of the structure you desire?

Comment: Look at your output: You're not dealing with arrays, but instances of `stdClass`, Objects require a different approach. If you can't work with them, either cast them to arrays (`$asArray = (array) $object`), or, if the object has properties that are objects, too: `$asArray = json_decode(json_encode($recursiveObject), true);`

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$category_ids = array_of_ids;

foreach($category_ids as $category_id) {
   $rowResult = $this->api->queryAllProducts(array('params' => array('categoryCode' => $category_id, 'usertoken' => USER_TOKEN))));
   foreach($rowResult->result->products->Product as $values) {
     $values->category_id = {HERE CODE TO GET category_id}
   }
  $queryAllProducts['products'][] = $rowResult;
 }
```

Comment: The code you given is adding next to result but not after productName. Any other changes need to be done

Comment: @Seting SO your $this->api->queryAllProducts result start from 'products'?

Comment: It starts from result

Comment: @Seting try the changes there

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
foreach($category_ids as $category_id) {
    $queryAllProducts['products'][] = $this->api->queryAllProducts(array('params' => array('categoryCode' => $category_id, 'usertoken' => USER_TOKEN))));
    $a = array_pop($queryAllProducts);
    $b = array_pop($a);
    $c = array_pop($b);
    $d = array_merge($c, array( 'category_id' => $category_id ));
    array_push($queryAllProducts,$d);
}
```

or maybe:

```
foreach($category_ids as $category_id) {
  $result = $this->api->queryAllProducts(array('params' => array('categoryCode' => $category_id, 'usertoken' => USER_TOKEN))));
    $a = array_pop($result);
    $b = array_merge($a, array( 'category_id' => $category_id ));
    $queryAllProducts['products'][] = $b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$this->api->queryAllProducts return cascading object array, so you should try to get product array from result then build your own array as per your requirement.

Here I have updated your code, try this.....

```
foreach($category_ids as $category_id) {
$rsobj = $this->api->queryAllProducts(array('params' => array('categoryCode' => $category_id, 'usertoken' => USER_TOKEN))));
$Products = $rsobj->result->products->Product;
foreach($Products as $product) {
    $queryAllProducts['products'][] = (object)array_merge($product, array('category_id' => something_which_is_from_$category_id));
}
```

}